# Meta data keeps showing as "## Build Setup" for every page in Vuejs/Nuxt?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, metadata

I've added individual meta to every page following the Nuxt documentation but whenever I share my links on social media, the meta just show this '## build setup'. Another issue is the same metadata is showing for every page. I read you need to put "hids" to have individual page meta but nothing seems to be working?

**Index Meta:**

```html
<script>
export default {
  head: {
    title: 'Animal Crossing Portal | The Best Tier Lists for Animal Crossing',
    meta: [
      { property: 'og:description', hid: 'og:description', name: 'og:description', content: 'Vote monthly in Animal Crossing Tier Lists for New Horizons & Pocket Camp! Including Villager Tier Lists, Sanrio, Gyroids & more at Animal Crossing Portal!' },
      { name: 'twitter:title', hid: 'twitter:title', content: 'Animal Crossing Portal | The Best Tier Lists for Animal Crossing' },
      { name: 'twitter:description', hid: 'twitter:description', content: 'Vote monthly in Animal Crossing Tier Lists for New Horizons & Pocket Camp! Including Villager Tier Lists, Sanrio, Gyroids & more at Animal Crossing Portal!' },
      { name: 'twitter:card', hid: 'twitter:card', content: 'summary_large_image' },
      { name: 'twitter:image:src', hid: 'twitter:image:src', content: 'https://www.animalcrossingportal.com/images/meta.jpg' },
      { property: 'og:title', hid: 'og:title', name: 'og:title', content: 'Animal Crossing Portal | The Best Tier Lists for Animal Crossing' },
      { property: 'og:type', hid: 'og:type', content: 'website' },
      { property: 'og:site_name', hid: 'og:site_name', content: 'Animal Crossing Portal' },
      { property: 'og:url', hid: 'og:url', content: 'https://www.animalcrossingportal.com/' },
      { property: 'og:image', hid: 'og:image', content: 'https://www.animalcrossingportal.com/images/meta.jpg' }
    ],
    link: [
      {
        rel: 'canonical',
        href: 'https://www.animalcrossingportal.com/'
      }
    ]
  }
}
</script>
```

**My nuxt.config.js file has:**

```js
head: {
    meta: [
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Did you searched for a `build setup` in your project? Do you have something like that there?

Comment: Hey kissu thanks for replying, that was my first thought. Unfortunately there's nothing with that in my code

Comment: Got a public repo for that one?

Comment: Oh actually, there was an instance of it which slipped my grip! I was searching all files and found it in the read me file. thought nothing of it at the time as I thought it was just a read me! I removed it, and it works now. thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it was the readme file, but after a few hours of digging (issue resurfaced), turns out it was actually an empty build tag in the nuxt config file which was making Nuxt try SSR. Removing the empty tag 100% fixed it.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but cant find an empty build tag in my nuxt config file : do you remember what was your faulty config like ?

Answer (score 2):

The meta was actually lying inside of a `README.md` file, removing it from there fixed OP's issue!

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue recently. After having a look into the source code view of the rendered page (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> in the browser), a quick search yielded that the meta-field `og:description` was not populated correctly. Correction of that was straightforward.

Thus, a look on your rendered page source code might reveal the missing/wrongly populated field (e.g. "description").